# Extracting image from a request body results with a corrupted image (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, image, file-io, outputstream

I have a problem that has been bugging me a whole week and I have come to a dead end.

This is the scenario: I have a method in a Java Spring Controller that handles a HTTP POST request. The POST request contains a picture. The twist is that the picture is not sent as multipart request, it is sent in the RequestBody (note for the answers saying to change the way of sending the picture: I have no access or possibility of doing this, I have to do with what I have).

So i extract the picture by using the input stream from the request. Then I open an Output stream and then write to the file, while I am reading from the input stream.

```
InputStream is =  request.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\M\\" + request.getHeader("Content-Location").toString()));
int x;
  while ((x = is.read()) != -1) {
    os.write(x);
    os.flush();
 }
os.close();
```

Nothing fancy, just plain old write as you read, byte by byte.

The problem is that the picture is shown as jpeg (as to be expected), but you can not open it (I have tried multiple viewers and got the same result):

> name_of_pic.jpg Decode error! Not a JPEG file: Starts with 0xbd 0xef

Then I said okay lets try another way or output stream for writing the picture. All of the following code got me the same result.

```
//alternative way1
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\M\\" + request.getHeader("Content-Location").toString())));

            while(dis.available()>0){
                int b = dis.read();//also tried with readByte, readUnsignedByte.. got 0kb file
                dos.write(b);
                dos.flush();
            }
            dos.close();
//alternative way2
    IOUtils.copy(is, os);

//alternative way3
int len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(buffer[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

So I looked at the requestBody in the debugger and compared it to what I have in the picture. There is a difference in the values that are stored in the requestBody and the values stored in the picture (after I write it on the filesystem).

This picture shows the few first values in the requestBody: http://prntscr.com/7cuiw5

And this is how the picture looks like in hex value (using irfanview hex editor):
http://prntscr.com/7culcn

Clearly there is a difference to what I get to what I write down.

The question is where does it go wrong? Is it a problem with the output stream that reads int? Or maybe its the conversion from hex to int/byte?

Anyway I am really stuck with this one. Any help at all would be really appreciated. I am sorry that I cant post the pictures directly (not so much reputation).

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Qinjie yes, as I remember the problem was with a custom filter in the http servlet request chain that was altering the request body.
Removed the custom filter and the code worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you will open the image in notepad,you'll see some extra code at the top and the bottom.

> -----------------------------119202331112770
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="..gif"
>
> Content-Type: image/gif

This code has to be removed if you wanna see your images.
these codes are present in the body of post method.